# SLF4J logger not logging

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, slf4j

The log file exists and logs are generated but it isn't logging `Processing index request` in the logs.

Is the code correct? When index page is accessed the thymleaf content "DevOps" is being retrieved and displayed in index.html but no logs from `logger.info` in the logs.

```
package com.example.devops.web;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    private final Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        logger.info("Processing index request");
        model.addAttribute("course", "DevOps");
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Log entires:

```
021-08-27 18:41:08.557 [INFO ] [localhost-startStop-1] c.e.d.ServletInitializer - Starting ServletInitializer v1.3.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_301 on DESKTOP-6O551TV with PID 23756 (F:\Devops\apache-tomcat-8.5.70\webapps\devops\WEB-INF\classes started by user in F:\Devops\apache-tomcat-8.5.70\bin)
2021-08-27 18:41:08.615 [INFO ] [localhost-startStop-1] c.e.d.ServletInitializer - The following profiles are active: dev
2021-08-27 18:41:09.573 [INFO ] [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 847 ms
2021-08-27 18:41:10.215 [INFO ] [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping - Adding welcome page template: index
2021-08-27 18:41:10.374 [INFO ] [localhost-startStop-1] c.e.d.ServletInitializer - Started ServletInitializer in 2.416 seconds (JVM running for 11.278)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually its working as expected. `application-dev.properties` file did not have full path of the log and a couple of commits were missing.

It is working.